# Issue with Microsoft OneNote(web view) Find Tags Displaying Repetitive Tag Names Instead of Individual Notes

Tags: tags, office365, onenote

I have noticed that when searching for a specific tag in OneNote's 'Find Tags' section, the results show the tag name repeated for each instance within a note, rather than listing the individual notes where the tag is applied. This occurs when same tag is applied to multiple notes. This makes it challenging to quickly locate and navigate  to the relevant notes. Has anyone else encountered this issue, and is there a solution or workaround available?

I have applied same tag to two of my notes and tried to search the notes associated with that tag using 'Find Tags' feature. But, it shows the tag name repeated twice in the search results. I was expecting those two notes to appear as a search result.